# Symfony2 : HWIOAuthBundle : Facebook login => amazing behavior

Tags: symfony, facebook-oauth, hwioauthbundle

I have both implemented in my website FOSUserBunle and HWIOAuthBunle. Classical login form (FOS) and Google login (HWI) work fine.

I have recently added Facebook login but when I try to log this way using this URI (simple link) from my login page

> mywebsite/fr/connect/facebook/

the login process is well initiated on Facebook side but I am redirected to my login page and the browser displays the following URI :

> mywebsite/fr/connect/#*=*

*=> As this point I am not logged (that is my main problem, the characters "#_=_" seems to be normal as described in different posts).*

I precise that :

- I use the connect functionnality of the Bundle (new user is recorded to DB but has to choose a password)
- I don't have any Facebook Login Button using Javascript SDK

To be more specific, my configuration here below :

**config.yml**

```
# HWIOauth Configuration
hwi_oauth:

    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    firewall_name: main 

    resource_owners:
        google:
            type:                google
            client_id:           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            client_secret:       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            scope:               "email profile"

        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            client_secret:       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            scope:               "email public_profile"

    fosub:
        # try 30 times to check if a username is available (foo, foo1, foo2 etc)
        username_iterations: 30

        # mapping between resource owners (see below) and properties
        properties:
            google: googleId
            facebook: facebookId

    connect: 
        confirmation: true
```

**routing.yml**

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/connect
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr    

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/connect
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr      

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/connect
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr     

google_login:
    pattern: /{_locale}/login/check-google
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr

facebook_login:
    pattern: /{_locale}/login/check-facebook
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr         

MyUserBundle:
    resource: "@MyUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/profile
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr          

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr        

# Other FOS routes...
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        #...

    role_hierarchy:
        #...

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email       

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path: mybundle_homepage
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: mybundle_homepage
                handlers: [mybundle_user.logout_handler]

            remember_me:
                key: %secret% 
                lifetime: 31536000 
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    google: google_login
                    facebook: facebook_login
                login_path:  fos_user_security_login
                use_forward: false
                failure_path: hwi_oauth_connect
                default_target_path: mybundle_homepage

                oauth_user_provider:        
                    service: mybundle_user.provider.fosub_bridge

    access_control:
        #...
```

**Facebook developpers console**

```
Apps Basic :

I use App ID for "client_id" in HWIOAUthBundle

Security section :

I use Client Token for "client_secret" in HWIOAUthBundle

OAuth Settings Section :

Client OAuth Login :
Yes

Valid OAuth redirect URIs :
http://mywebsite/fr/login/check-facebook
http://mywebsite/en/login/check-facebook
http://mywebsite/fr/connect/service/facebook
http://mywebsite/en/connect/service/facebook
```

Comment: Problem solved. Due to some modifications in my twig files (without any importance here), I could not the see the following error : "Error validating client secret". The correct "client secret" to be configured in HWIOAuthBundle is not "Client Token" in Security Section but "App Secret" in Apps Basic menu.